# CQRS and Event Sourcing Guide

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, cqrs, event-sourcing

I want to create a **CQRS and Event Sourcing** architecture that is very cheap and very flexible and very uncomplicated.

I want to make sure that events never fail to at least reach the publisher/event store, ever, ever, because that's where business is.

Now, i have several options in mind:

**Azure**

With azure, i seem to not know what to use.

1. Azure service bus
2. Azure Function
3. Azure webjob (i suppose this can be replaced with Azure functions)
4. ?? (something else i forgot or dont know?)

***How reliable are these azure server-less solutions??***

**Custom**

For this i am thinking of using RabbitMQ, the problem is the cost of a virtual machine to run it.

---

### All in all, i want:

1. Ability to replay the messages/events in case of failure.
2. Ability to easily add subscribers.
3. Ability to select the subscribers upon which to replay the messages.
4. The Event store should be able to store very large sizes of event messages (or how else shall queue an image or file??).
5. The event store MUST NEVER EVER get chocked, or sleep.
6. Speed of implementation/prototyping would be an added
   advantage.

---

What does your experience suggest?

What about other alternatives? (eg: `apache-kafka`)?

Answer (score 2):

Why not run Event Store? Created by Greg Young himself. Host where you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am a java user, I have been using hornetq (aka artemis which I dont use) an alternative to rabbitmq for the longest; the only problem is it does not support replication but gets the job done when it comes to eventsourcing.  For your custom scenario, rabbitmq is a good choice but try running it on a digital ocean instance for low costs. If you are looking for simplicity and flexibility you have only 2 choices , build your own or forgo simplicity and pick up apache kafka with all its complexities but will give you flexibility. Again you can also build an eventstore with mongodb. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/event-sourcing-with-mongodb

Comment: Regarding building your own event store: this is really bad advice. Event stores have enough complex requirements to make building your own quite a difficult task, and a lot of people do not seem to be aware of these when they first get introduced to event sourcing,

Comment: Also (given this get's suggested regularly) and just in case, do not use kafka as the event store, as it lacks concurrency checks on write, causing you to potentially end up with wrong data.

Comment: I hear you however it really depends on the use case. You don't need to pick up a whole framework just to do minor event sourcing. If you are doing it at scale I would truly understand the need for going in that direction but for minor event sourcing create simple event sourcing application and use that in the interim.

Comment: @SavvasKleanthous One more thing, watch Greg Youngs '8 lines of code' and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9a1PqwFrMP0&ab_channel=NDCConferences. You can always build your own, there's no standard way of doing it, just a bunch of principles you need to understand.

Comment: I am very well aware of Greg's and Mat's talks, and I know both of them personally. Writing code to rehydrate state from events is a VASTLY different type of problem than building an event store. Have a look here: https://github.com/ylorph/RandomThoughts/blob/master/2019.08.09_expectations_for_an_event_store.md

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are too vague to make the optimal choice. You need to consider a lot of things, one of them would be, for instance, the numbers of events per one aggregate, the number of aggregates (note that this has to be statistical). Those are important primarily because if you allow tens of thousands of events for each aggregate then you would need to have snapshotting which adds complexity which you might not need.

But for regular use cases you could just use a relational database like Postgres as your (linearizable) event store. It also has a listen/notify functionality to you would not really need any message bus either and your application could be written in a reactive way.